# Resultを返すようなiterでのエラーハンドリングについて

Tags: rust

文字列の集合`["1", "xxx", "3"]`を順に数字に`parse::<i32>`していき
変換が**最後まで完遂**できたら、**最後のパース結果**を返し
途中で**一度でもパースに失敗したら**エラーを返すような関数`parse_and_last`を作りたいです。

その際、一度パースに失敗した場合、以降のパースは**行わないようにしたい**です。

私の書いたコードは以下になりますが、途中でVecを作成してしまっています。
これを`Iter`メソッドのみで行う方法は存在するでしょうか？

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() {
    let v_ok: Vec<&str> = vec!["1", "2", "3"];
    println!("{:?}", parse_and_last(&v_ok)); // => Ok(3)

    let v_err: Vec<&str> = vec!["1", "xxx", "3"];
    println!("{:?}", parse_and_last(&v_err)); // => Err(ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit })
}

fn parse_and_last(v: &[&str]) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let results: Result<Vec<i32>, _> = v
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.parse::<i32>().map(|s| s))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<i32>, _>>();

    results.map(|v: Vec<i32>| (*v.last().unwrap()))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust 1.27.0から導入された `try_fold` を使うとできます。（[ドキュメント](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold)）

```
fn parse_and_last(v: &[&str]) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    // vが空ではないことを確認する
    // これがないとvが空のときにtry_foldの初期値0が使われ、Ok(0)が返ってしまう
    assert!(!v.is_empty());

    // Errが返るまでパースを続ける。Errがなかったときは最後のOkが返る
    v.iter().try_fold(0, |_acc, s| s.parse())
}
```